# jQuery File Upload multiple independent widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I've seen the other discussion here on stackoverflow concerning question, but as it is frequently happens it was no working solutions - it was like "try to do that and see what's happens"
So, I need in at least two completely independent file upload widgets - no picture previews, single file upload for each widget, no query. The working code for others who want to save a few days of worktime:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
<style type="text/css">

.bar {
    height: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    height: 25px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #0ba1b5;
    border-radius: 3px; 
}

.container{
    width: 25em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px 10px 5px 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

input[type=file]{
    width:6.8em;
    color:transparent;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.validate.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.pressed = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('fileupload');
    if(a.value == "")  { fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose file";  }
           else        { var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
                         fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
                       }
                           };

window.pressed2 = function(){
    var a2 = document.getElementById('fileupload2');
    if(a2.value == "")  { fileLabel2.innerHTML = "Choose file";  }
           else        { var theSplit2 = a2.value.split('\\');
                         fileLabel2.innerHTML = theSplit2[theSplit2.length-1];
                       }
                            };

function HumanFileSize(fileSizeInBytes) {
    var i = -1;
    var byteUnits = [' kB', ' MB', ' GB', ' TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    do { fileSizeInBytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
         i++;
       } while (fileSizeInBytes > 1024);
    return Math.max(fileSizeInBytes, 0.1).toFixed(1) + byteUnits[i];
};

     $(function () {
        'use strict';

        // Define the url to send the image data to
        var url = '/cgi-bin/files.php';
        var url2 = '/cgi-bin/files2.php';

        // Call the fileupload widget and set some parameters
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',

            submit: function (e, data) {
                // Add each uploaded file name to the #files list
           $('#files').hide();
           $("#files").html("");
           $('#progress').show();

            },

            done: function (e, data) {
           $('#progress').hide();
           $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<label>Uploaded: ' + HumanFileSize(file.size) + '</label>').appendTo('#files');
                                            });
           $('#files').show();

            },


        fail: function (e, data) {
            $('#progress').hide();
            $('#files').show();
            $.each(data.messages, function (index, error) {
                $('<p style="color: red;">Upload file error: ' + error + '<i class="elusive-remove" style="padding-left:10px;"/></p>').appendTo('#files');
                                                              });
                                     },

            progressall: function (e, data) {
                // Update the progress bar while files are being uploaded
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        });

        $('#fileupload2').fileupload({
            url: url2,
            dataType: 'json',

             add: function (e, data) {
                  data.submit();
            },

            submit: function (e, data) {
                // Add each uploaded file name to the #files3 list
           $('#files3').hide();
           $("#files3").html("");
           $('#progress2').show();

            },

            done: function (e, data) {
            $('#progress2').hide();
        $.each(data.result.files2, function (index, file) {
                $('<label>Uploaded: ' + HumanFileSize(file.size) + '</label>').appendTo('#files3');

                                           });
           $('#files3').show();

            },

            progressall: function (e, data) {
                // Update the progress bar while files are being uploaded
                var progress2 = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress2 .bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress2 + '%'
                );
            }
        });


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<th style="min-width:28em;auto !important;_width:28em">Dataset1</th>
<th style="min-width:28em;auto !important;_width:28em">Dataset2</th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" onchange="pressed()"><label id="fileLabel">Choose file</label>
</td>
<td>
<input id="fileupload2" type="file" name="files2[]" onchange="pressed2()"><label id="fileLabel2">Choose file</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="files" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="progress" class="container" style="display:none;">
<div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="files3" class="files" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="progress2" class="container" style="display:none;">
<div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

files.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('blueImpUploader.php');
$options = array ('upload_dir'     => '/tmp/files/',
                  'image_versions' => array()); 
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
?>
```

files2.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('blueImpUploader.php');
$options = array ('upload_dir'     => '/tmp/files/',
                  'image_versions' => array(),
          'param_name'     => 'files2'); 
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
?>
```

The question is how can I add file verification BEFORE upload? I'd like to accept only few file extensions, but both "normal" and gzipped - I mean .bed and .bed.gz, .sgr and .sgr.gz. I cannot do it neither by processing add: function (e,data) nor by entering appropriate extensions in files.php. Or, I'd say, it's working partially - some extensions are filtered, some are not.